# Excel Files Temporary Exist?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to find out where an Excel workbook exists BEFORE it is ever saved? I've searched for it using the time and date of creation but wondering if creation really means first save? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Has it been saved again?

Comment: Are you looking for the temp file created when a new workbook is created, but yet to be saved? Or are you looking for the the template all new workbooks are based from?

Comment: By "saved", do you mean manually saved by you, or the recovery copy that is periodically written to disk when auto-save is on?  If auto-save is enabled, I believe the recovery copy is in a subdirectory several branches under appdata.  If you mean before anything is written to disk, it exists only in RAM.

Comment: Yes CharlieRB I am looking for the temp file before the workbook is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are saved under your user profile's temporary file folder.  Excel also cleans these files up, so it's likely you data is deleted if you haven't saved it or Excel has been closed since then.